# License Text Coverage

Tags: license-notice

I plan to use the following library https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift. For this library a convenient license is displayed on the front page.

The issue I see is that when I go inside the project (e.g here https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/tree/master/Sources/CryptoSwift/AES.swift) a copyright notice is displayed.

The question is: which license applies to the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue I see is that when I go inside the project (e.g here https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/tree/master/Sources/CryptoSwift/AES.swift) a copyright notice is displayed.

That's fine. It is usual for the author to retain the copyright while *licensing* the work under to others under a permissive license. The fact that the code has been licensed does not undermine the author's copyright ownership in any way; for example the author is free to license the code under other a proprietary license as well.

The phrase "[all rights reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_rights_reserved)" does not contradict the licensing of the software. In the past this phrasing was required to claim copyright in some jurisdictions; today it has no legal effect because copyright is automatic in most legal jurisdictions. Thus at most this phrase means that copyright is being claimed, not that that particular file is not being licensed under the project license.

More specifically, the "rights" that are being "reserved" are the property rights in the copyright itself. It's a little confusing because without knowing the legal history a layperson might well assume that "all rights reserved" means something like exclusive distribution; it does not.

Comment: Thank you for that, it is most informative.  I've added a supporting link; I hope that's OK.

Comment: @MadHatter Well it's still accurate that "the content cannot be copied freely" as you must abide by the author's 3-clause license. If it were "copyable freely" (as in public domain), you could, for example, refuse to provide an acknowledgement in your product documentation as required by the license.

Comment: I understood your point to be that "all rights reserved" has no legal function any more, and therefore does not serve to restrict the use of that file over and above those rights granted in the project LICENCE file.  I did not understand you to suggest that putting "all rights reserved" somehow waived even the project licence terms.  But thanks for clarifying that anyway!  All clarity is good, in these issues.